# Jquery Select the clicked div among other divs with the same class

Tags: jquery, css, hidden, addclass, slidetoggle

Basically I have a gallery(grid) that when each individual block is clicked it reveals a hidden div. I have that functionality working. I also have a color overlay on each block that disappears on hover. I also want the hidden div parent block to not have the overlay - when the hidden div is visible. At the moment it removes the overlay off all of the parent blocks and it should be only the parent bloc that is showing the hidden div. Look at the fiddle for further understanding.

```
$(".glry-itm").click(function() {
    $(".hidden").slideUp();
    if ($(".hidden").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle(300);
        $(".glry-itm").addClass("On");

    } else{

        $(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle(300);
        $(".glry-itm").addClass("Off");
   }

});
```

[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6zqr5qv1/)

Comment: You need this? http://jsfiddle.net/6zqr5qv1/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `$(".glry-itm").addClass("On");` and I used `$(this)`  instead of `(".glry-itm")`

```
 $(".glry-itm").click(function() {
    $(".glry-itm").addClass("On");
    $(".hidden").slideUp();
    $(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle(300);
    if ($(".hidden:visible")) {
        $(this).removeClass("On");
        $(this).addClass("Off");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("Off");
        $(this).addClass("On");
    }
});
```

[Edited Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6zqr5qv1/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).addClass("On");` instead of `$(".glry-itm").addClass("On");`

`$(".glry-itm").addClass("On");` will add class to all the `glry-itm` elements. If you use `this` inside the click hander, it will add the class to current clicked element

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6zqr5qv1/2/)

Comment: Close but that only affects the first one clicked. I need it to effect which  \ever one (block) is clicked. Ie your solution is 1st block not colored but it could be any hidden div showing. I need the Bloc and Hidden div to be parallel Ie if the 3rd block is clicked it shouldn't be orange and the 3rd hidden div is showing. I need it to change every time a different block is clicked

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, remove `:before` from `.Off`:

```
  .Off {
    background: none;
  }
```

As here: http://jsfiddle.net/6zqr5qv1/4/

Also, you can factor this line out of your if/then/else, and just have it once, before the if:

```
  $(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle(300);
```

Comment: This makes sense and cleans up my code but it doesn't the off / on is working as it should. When the hidden div is visible the parent .glry-itm should be off.